How to merge and simplify a list of 2D polygons?
I have a list of 2D polygons represented as List<double[]> in Java defining gemetries of streets. Each array represents a polygon with coordinates in pairs (x1, y1, x2, y2, ...). For example, a polygon might be represented as {x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x1, y1}.
I want to obtain a simplified list of polygons by merging polygons that can be combined into a single polygon. All polygons in the list are simple, with no oriented rings or self-intersections.
I've tried using JTS (Java Topology Suite), but the results are not as expected. Here are the images
Before polygon merging

After polygon merging

I've ensured the polygons are correctly defined multiple times, but as shown in the images, the merging produces unexpected results.
**Here's the code I've tried: **
public class PolygonMerger {
    
    public static List<double[]> mergePolygons(List<double[]> polygons) {
        List<Geometry> jtsPolygons = new ArrayList<>();
        GeometryFactory factory = new GeometryFactory();

        for (double[] coords : polygons) {
            Coordinate[] coordinates = new Coordinate[coords.length / 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < coords.length; i += 2) {
                coordinates[i / 2] = new Coordinate(coords[i], coords[i + 1]);
            }
            
            // Ensure the polygon is closed
            if (!coordinates[0].equals(coordinates[coordinates.length - 1])) {
                Coordinate[] closedCoordinates = new Coordinate[coordinates.length + 1];
                System.arraycopy(coordinates, 0, closedCoordinates, 0, coordinates.length);
                closedCoordinates[coordinates.length] = coordinates[0]; // Close the polygon
                coordinates = closedCoordinates;
            }

            // Create the polygon
            Polygon polygon = factory.createPolygon(coordinates);
            
            // Validate and repair the polygon if needed
            if (!new IsValidOp(polygon).isValid()) {
                polygon = (Polygon) polygon.buffer(0); // Repair polygon
            }
            
            jtsPolygons.add(polygon);
        }
        
        // Union all polygons
        Geometry mergedGeometry = CascadedPolygonUnion.union(jtsPolygons);
        List<Polygon> mergedPolygons = new ArrayList<>();
        
        if (mergedGeometry instanceof Polygon) {
            mergedPolygons.add((Polygon) mergedGeometry);
        } else if (mergedGeometry instanceof MultiPolygon) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mergedGeometry.getNumGeometries(); i++) {
                mergedPolygons.add((Polygon) mergedGeometry.getGeometryN(i));
            }
        }
        
        return convertToDoubleArrays(mergedPolygons);
    }
    
    private static List<double[]> convertToDoubleArrays(List<Polygon> polygons) {
        List<double[]> polygonCoordsList = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for (Polygon polygon : polygons) {
            Coordinate[] coordinates = polygon.getExteriorRing().getCoordinates();
            double[] coordsArray = new double[coordinates.length * 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
                coordsArray[i * 2] = coordinates[i].x;
                coordsArray[i * 2 + 1] = coordinates[i].y;
            }
            
            polygonCoordsList.add(coordsArray);
        }
        
        return polygonCoordsList;
    }
}

What could be causing the unexpected results, and how can I fix them? Are there potential issues with the merging process or the polygon definitions that I might have overlooked?

A [MCVE] might improve this Question.

If your polygons are all closed, (which it looks like you check for in your code), then you can use the Java.awt.geom.Area class to combine polygons. As you loop through your polygons and after you create your polygons,
Polygon polygon = factory.createPolygon(coordinates);

you can then combine all intersecting polygons into one by converting using the Area class:
Area polyArea = new Area(polygon);
Area sectPolyArea = new Area(intersectingPolygon);
polyArea.add(sectPolyArea);

Once you have your areas, if you want to convert them back to polygons or a List<double[]> you can use a PathIterator:
PathIterator iterator = polyArea.getPathIterator(null);
float[] floats = new float[6];
//you can use a Polygon here or a double[]
//if you want double precision then I suggest using a double[] because the Polygon class only supports integer precision
Polygon newPoly = new Polygon();
while(!iterator.isDone()) {
    int type = iterator.currentSegment(floats);
    float x = floats[0];
    float y = floats[1];
    if (type != PathIterator.SEG_CLOSE) {
        newPoly.addPoint((int)x, (int)y);
    }
    iterator.next();
}

I have not used JTS before so I do not know what the unexpected result was from, but it appears that it was filling the space between sets of points that enclose an area. Perhaps the polygons weren't fully closed when they were combined, leading to polygons that were not intersecting being combined.
